# How to find the Wi-Fi Password of a Connected Network on Android mobile

Tags: wifi-password

Is it Possible to know that in android devices, what are the supported versions are available, please share your ideas.

Comment: It is unclear what you asking... flagging as unclear for possible deletion unless updated

Comment: @eldarerathis i kindly request you  please share the existing link.  where it is located, thanks a lot.

Comment: The link is at the top of your question, in the yellow box labelled "This question already has an answer here: <link>"

Comment: Sorry Bro, I'm not well-wisher about This Site, i'm sorry for made this question. thank you for help.

Answer (score 3):

You will be needing a rooted android for this.

If you want to view your saved WiFi password in your Android phone without using any apps, follow these steps:

1. Using your file explorer navigate to `/data/wifi` or `/data/misc/wifi`. This directory varies by device. Just know that you are looking for a folder named "wifi" (or for easy approach direct search for `wpa_supplicant.conf`).
2. Once you are inside the directory, open the file `wpa_supplicant.conf` with a text viewer.
3. You will find all your saved passwords inside that file. Password will be stored as:

   ```
   network={
       ssid="WiFiName"
       psk="password"
       key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
       priority=1
   }
   ```

Note that this requires your device to be rooted. Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

First off, you usually need a rooted device. Secondly, you can find the info usually in `/data/misc/wifi/wpa-supplicant.conf`. You can use `cat` via `adb shell` to get to this, or read it in an Android text editor of your choice.

Answer (score -1):

What you will have to do is go to Chrome, type in the IP address of the router and proceed to your WLAN settings. This will yield the WiFi password.